# Star magnitude mini lights

Tags: light

I would like to display the big and little dippers on the outside back wall of my house using mini light bulbs of appropriate  intensities.  I converted  those 14 star magnitudes to lumins.  Unitizing there luminosity gives a range of 1 for the dimmest star to 32 for the brightest.  Finding 120v bulbs in the 14 different wattages needed is not possible.  Is it possible to use individual resisters on each bulb to get the effect desired?  I also am considering using fiber optics with a single light source to provide the desired effect.

Comment: Why not use LEDs, driven with calibrated current sources?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy method is incandescent bulbs with individual dimmers. Slightly different, led bulbs with led compatible dimmers. Or smart led bulbs which you can set to a percentage of light via your phone.

Harder would be a custom dimmer controller with triacs or ssr and compatible bulbs. Or go DC with a constant current led driver and the appropriate led modules. This can provide twinkling effects if you program it to.

But smart led bulbs is probably the easiest.